# How to interpret the following JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Given the following code segment (it comes from blueimp extending jquery.fileupload-image.js) I need help figuring out the part - see the larger section below my text:

```
!loadImage(
    file, 
    function(img) { 
       if(img.src) { 
          data.img = img; 
       } 
       dfd.resolveWith(that, [data]); 
    }, 
    options 
)) { 
return data;
}
```

When I step through the code using debug when a valid JPEG image file has been dropped on the browser it will go through the the if(($.type(options... and enter the !loadImage( part above, then it will go to the return dfd.promise(); statement and go back to line data.img = img; where a valid image will be defined.

I don't know what is going on, where is !loadImage(... actually going to load the JPEG image data?

What I am ultimately trying to do is to get it to display a CIELAB TIFF image I have changed the options.filetypes settings so that it will now accept a standard RGBA TIFF image and display it correctly. I have some custom code that will display a CIELAB TIFF image in a browser but I just don't know enough about this code below to figure out where to correctly modify it to insert my custom code to get data.img = img; with the return from my custom code that will give it the returned img data of a CIELAB TIFF. My custom code that will read a CIELAB TIFF image puts in to a canvas object. When I drag a CIELAB TIFF image onto the browser it will enter the if(($.type(... statement and then hit the return dfd.promise(); statement but it does not go back to the data.img = img; like it does when I do a JPEG drag and drop so img is undefined.

Can someone explain the code below to me and help me with how to modify correctly to insert my custom javascript that reads a CIELAB TIFF image and get it correctly into data.img = img; below? (Note your dealing with a old C and C# guy that dates back to the PDP-11 and TECO editor dark ages so go gently on me I'll need a lot of hand-holding to get through this - thanks).

```
processActions: {

        // Loads the image given via data.files and data.index
        // as img element, if the browser supports the File API.
        // Accepts the options fileTypes (regular expression)
        // and maxFileSize (integer) to limit the files to load:
        loadImage: function (data, options) {
            if (options.disabled) {
                return data;
            }
            var that = this,
                file = data.files[data.index],
                dfd = $.Deferred();
            if (($.type(options.maxFileSize) === 'number' && file.size > options.maxFileSize) ||
                (options.fileTypes && !options.fileTypes.test(file.type)) ||
                    !loadImage(
                        file,
                        function (img) {
                            if (img.src) {
                                data.img = img;
                            }
                            dfd.resolveWith(that, [data]);
                        },
                        options
                    )) {
                return data;
            }
            return dfd.promise();
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

*(For clarity I reduced the if statement)*

The first part is a part of the if statement:

```
if (foo || bar || 
!loadImage(
    file,
    function (img) {
        if (img.src) {
            data.img = img;
        }
        dfd.resolveWith(that, [data]);
    },
    options
)
```

while the second part is the block to execute if the statement is truthy.

```
){
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I think what I am struggling with is the: !loadImage(file, function(img) { if (img.src) { data.img = img; } dfd.resolveWith(that, [data]); }, options  - I'm do not understand what is going on with this section?

Comment: it calling a function with 3 parameters: "file", an anonymous function, and "options".  the signature of loadImage is probably `function loadImage(files, callback, options) { ...`. functions in javascript are first class citizens and are common to be passed as arguments

Comment: Uzi I starting get it your definition above helped a lot can you better explain function (img) { data.img = img; } dfd.resolveWith(that, [data]); how does this part work?

Comment: Read about  javascript promises and the $.Deferred() object. this is a function that will accept an object that reperests and image, and if it has a source it will assign that to data.img. it revolves the deferred object with the data. not sure what you're asking, but do some reading about js and promises is my best advice

Comment: Uzi - thanks I will start looking into more in depth javascript anonymous functions and javascript promises and $.Deferred() object.